# How to aggregate a data.frame on both row and column names based on a hierarchical dictionary name structure?

Tags: r, data.table

(apologies, I wasn't sure what the best title for this post would be, feel free to edit).

Lets say I have the following relational structure between words and their type (i.e. a dictionary):

```
dictionary <- data.frame(level1=c(rep("Positive", 3), rep("Negative", 3)), level2 = c("happy", "fantastic", "great", "sad", "rubbish", "awful"))

#     level1    level2
# 1 Positive     happy
# 2 Positive fantastic
# 3 Positive     great
# 4 Negative       sad
# 5 Negative   rubbish
# 6 Negative     awful
```

and we have counted their occurrences across seven documents (i.e. a term-document matrix):

```
set.seed(42)
range = 0:3
df <- data.frame(row.names = c("happy", "fantastic", "great", "sad", "rubbish", "awful"), doc1 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE), doc2 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE), doc3 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE), doc4 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE), doc5 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE), doc6 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE), doc7 = sample(x=range, size=6, replace=TRUE))

#           doc1 doc2 doc3 doc4 doc5 doc6 doc7
# happy        3    2    3    1    0    2    0
# fantastic    3    0    1    2    2    3    0
# great        1    2    1    3    1    1    3
# sad          3    2    3    0    3    2    2
# rubbish      2    1    3    3    1    0    1
# awful        2    2    0    3    3    3    1
```

Then I can easily calculate how often two words appear in the same document (i.e. a co-occurrence or adjacency matrix):

```
# binary to indicate a co-occurrence
df[df > 0] <- 1
# sum co-occurrences
m <- as.matrix(df) %*% t(as.matrix(df))

#           happy fantastic great sad rubbish awful
# happy         5         4     5   4       4     4
# fantastic     4         5     5   4       4     4
# great         5         5     7   6       6     6
# sad           4         4     6   6       5     5
# rubbish       4         4     6   5       6     5
# awful         4         4     6   5       5     6
```

**Question:** How can I restructure my co-occurrence matrix so that I am looking at the word type (level1) in the dictionary rather that just the words themselves (level2)?

i.e. I would like:

```
data.frame(row.names = c("Positive", "Negative"), Positive = c(5+4+5+4+5+5+5+5+7, 4+4+6+4+4+6+4+4+6), Negative = c(4+4+4+4+4+4+6+6+6, 6+5+5+5+6+5+5+5+6))

#          Positive Negative
# Positive       45       42
# Negative       42       48
```

---

**What I've done thus far:** Previously I had hoped to be able to deduce the process from this question [Sum together columns of data.frame based on name type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321053/sum-together-columns-of-data-frame-based-on-name-type)

However whilst I can reduce the rows:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(m)
dt[, level1:=c(rep("Positive", 3), rep("Negative", 3))]
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "level1"]

#      level1 happy fantastic great sad rubbish awful
# 1: Positive    14        14    17  14      14    14
# 2: Negative    12        12    18  16      16    16
```

I can't work out how to reduce the columns as require.

Comment: +1 for a well structured question with reproducible example

Comment: hehe, cheers, I'm trying to make sure I avoid the ire of http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106/r

Comment: +1. Ooh, everything gets a special "id est" name!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically same solution as the other two so far, just a bit more compact and probably a bit faster:

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

mdt = data.table(melt(m), key = 'Var1')
dic = data.table(dictionary, key = 'level2')

dcast(dic[setkey(dic[mdt], Var2)], level1 ~ level1.1, fun.aggregate = sum)
#    level1 Negative Positive
#1 Negative       48       42
#2 Positive       42       45
```

Answer (score 6):

Continuing from `df[df > 0] <- 1`

```
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

# incorporating @RicardoSaporta's suggestion of using data.table(keep.rownames = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(as.matrix(df) %*% t(as.matrix(df)), keep.rownames = TRUE)

#reducing matrix format to plain data format, look at dt to see the change
dt <- melt(dt, "rn")

#getting positive/negative for word1 and word2
dt <- merge(dt,dictionary, all.x = TRUE, by.y = "level2", by.x = "rn")
dt <- merge(dt,dictionary, all.x = TRUE, by.y = "level2", by.x = "variable", suffixes = c("_1","_2"))


#getting counts for each positive/negative - positive/negative combination
dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[,list(value = sum(value)), by = c("level1_1","level1_2")]

#structuring
cast(dt,level1_1~level1_2, fun.aggregate=sum)
```

Output

```
> cast(dt,level1_1~level1_2, fun.aggregate=sum)
  level1_1 Negative Positive
1 Negative       48       42
2 Positive       42       45
```

Comment: just a tip: instead of those first two lines, you could use `dt <- as.data.table( ..., keep.rownames=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

You could go back a step, doing the aggregation on the adjacency matrix before creating the co-occurence matrix:

```
dict <- data.table(dictionary,key='level2')
adj2 <- data.table(df,keep.rownames=TRUE)

adj1 <- adj2[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=dict[rn]$level1]

# one tedious step:
adj1mat           <- as.matrix(adj1[,-1])
rownames(adj1mat) <- as.character(adj1$dict)

m1   <- adj1mat %*% t(adj1mat)

#          Positive Negative
# Positive       45       42
# Negative       42       48
```

It will make sense to have your dictionary stored as a keyed data.table anyway, I expect.

Comment: Frank, hey! What's `adj` in your 3rd line? Is it supposed to be `adj2`? It wont work because of the column `rn` then.

Comment: @Arun Right you are. Thanks! I also just realized that it only works because the by= removes "rn" from .SD.

Answer (score 3):

We can `aggregate` your matrix `m` using `by` twice. We just have to turn level2 words into level1 words using `match` first. I am pretty sure you can do this in one call, but I can't quite fathom it. Two calls ain't so bad.

```
#  Match Positive and Negative to words
colnames(m) <- dictionary$level1[ match( colnames( m ) ,  dictionary$level2 ) ]
rownames(m) <- dictionary$level1[ match( rownames( m ) ,  dictionary$level2 ) ]


#  Aggregate down to desired result
tmp <- do.call( cbind , by( m , INDICES = colnames(m) , FUN=colSums ) )
do.call(cbind , by( tmp , INDICES = rownames(m) , FUN=colSums ) )
#         Negative Positive
#Negative       48       42
#Positive       42       45
```